# Play M3U from browser

Tags: sound

I want to listen to online radio station from TuneIn [(This is an example radio station)](http://tunein.com/radio/Super-Estereo-s183518/). However, the M3U stream doesn't play from my browser (both chrome and firefox).

The fact is that I **do not have any problem** when using my Windows OS.

Do you know how I can fix that?

Comment: It is working flawlessly in my firefox. Could you please ellaborate your error?

Comment: @Raphael It just doesn't play :) Nothing more that that. Every station I tried plays except M3Us.

Comment: @Raphael I have also updated my question to say that I cannot play the station neither from chrome nor from firefox.

Comment: E.g.; If I go here: http://tunein.com/radio/Top-40Pop-c57943/ I can play the music flawlessly. Please say if it works for you?

Comment: @Raphael yes, that plays flowlessly here as well. However, many radio stations don't. Like the one I mentioned earlier or the BBC one: http://tunein.com/radio/BBC-Radio-1-988-s24939/

Comment: @Raphael is it possible that your browser uses a media player plugin than my browsers(from a clean Ubuntu 14.04 install) don't have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I visited the link [you provided:](http://tunein.com/radio/BBC-Radio-1-988-s24939/)

[image: TI]

- **When opening the link with firefox:**

a. I click on "Download this stream to listen". I get this window:

[image: W]

b. Here, I click on "Leafpad" and then click on other.

c. Then, I goto Filesystem > usr > bin. Here, I select "vlc".

[image: vlc]

d. When I click "Open", I get this window and the music starts playing.

[image: M]

- **When opening the link with chrome:**

a. I click on "Download this stream to listen", it gets downloaded.

b. Then, I click on "Show in folder".

[image: C]

c. Then, when the folder opens, I right-click on it and select "Open With" and then, select vlc.

[image: l]

I finally, get the previous window and the music starts playing.

Hope! this works for you too. Thank You!

Comment: Thanks a lot Raphael. Very nice solution. However, is it possible to make the file play from the browser as well, like it plays flawlessly in Windows without opening external programs? :) Is there any way to do that?

Comment: I don't know but some of the links play from the browser like the one I shared with you and some don't like the one you shared. Let me check if I can help you on that. Glad! it helped.

Comment: Yeah, thanks a lot!!! Very helpful and detailed solution:) I can now play the files :). If there is also any way to do that from the browser it will be amazing

Comment: Yeah I am trying to find out too. And if the solution was to your liking please accept the answer :-P Thank You!

Comment: Of course! I have just upvoted the answer and selected it as best answer :) Also, I just hope that there is any solution to play the stations from the browser :)

Comment: I am looking to it right now. And thank you sooo much!

Comment: I will comment in this question when I find a solution.

Comment: Any luck @Raphael? Btw as I understood the M3u just contains the actual link(that cannot play at the browser) which is of type asx... Therefore we should look for that I guess...

Comment: I couldn't find out and yeah I noticed that. I shall keep trying.